# Understanding this nested for loop to display prime numbers in C++

Tags: c++, primes

I am a beginner in coding, so I am confused about the following sample code to display prime numbers less than 20.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int i, j;

for(i = 2; i<20; i++) 
{
  for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++)
     if(i%j==0) break; 
     if(j > (i/j)) cout << i << " is prime\n";

}
return 0;
}
```

So let's say for the first looping, i = 2, I first choose have j = 2. Then, in line 8, I have if(i%j == 0) break; i = j = 2 does satisfy this condition. So why does my output still have 2 as one of the prime numbers?

P.S. I do know 2 is a prime number, but I am not understanding the code. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the `break;` take you in the code?

Comment: j<=(i/2) in for loop and j>i/2 after the loop will help

Comment: Have you omitted brackets or is your indentation wrong? the second `if` is not in the inner loop. (From the logic of the code, your indentation is wrong. Brackets would still be helpful.) Aside from that, j = 2 is not reached for i = 2 as `j <= (i/2)` evaluates as `2 <= 2/2` which is false.

Comment: Your indenting of line 9 is throwing people off their game.  It's not part of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop:

```
for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++)
```

doesn't pass `j <= (i/j)` the first time when `i = 2`.

And:

```
 if(j > (i/j)) cout << i << " is prime\n";
```

isn't part of that `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I have got it now.

Comment: You're totally welcome. The code would be a lot more readable with curly braces (`{` and `}`) around **all** the `for` loops' and `if` statements' blocks of code. Asking for trouble when they're left out of one line code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

If we rewrite your code like this :

```
for (i = 2; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) break;
    }
    if (j > (i / j)) cout << i << " is prime\n";
}
```

then it will be more clear that `break` will only break out of inner loop and next line (which prints 2) will get executed afterward.

Answer (score 0):

factors between two to n/2, to check prime number or not

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
 int i, j;

 for(i = 2; i<20; i++)
{
  for(j = 2; j <= (i/2); j++)
   if(i%j==0) break;
 if(j > (i/2)) cout << i << " is prime\n";

}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints `2` because when `i=2`, `j=2`, the condition of the inner loop fails(`2 > 2/2`).

Another interesting fact about this code is **why** you only go up to `i/j` to find primes. That is because composite number has prime factor not greater than its square root([demonstration](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composite_Number_has_Prime_Factor_not_Greater_Than_its_Square_Root)).

So, basically `j` goes only `2` up to `sqrt(i)`.

Also you can clean your code if you change the `for` condition from `j <= i/j` to `j*j <= i`. Why? Because as `i/j` is a integer division you need the extra condition `if(j > (i/j))`. So the final code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int i, j;

  for(i = 2; i<20; i++) 
  {
    for(j = 2; j*j <= i; j++)
       if(i%j==0) break; 
    cout << i << " is prime\n";

  }
  return 0;
}
```